# How to find all new rows in a mysql table that were added in the last week (with no date column in table)

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if it is possible to find all new rows in a table that were added in the last week if the table has no date column to signify when a given row was inserted into the table?

If so, can someone please advise me on how to accomplish this?

Or do I require a date column?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is a timestamp, then you can select any particular period.

Alternatives would be an autoincrement field and you record the last number of the previous wee.

Or you have a status field that defaults to "NEW" and then you set it to "OLD" or whatever once you have processed it.

Answer (score 1):

You do need some kind of timestamp, Or keep external records somewhere, what was added last week ;-). Do you have some sort of auto-incrementing column id?

Answer (score 1):

You do need a date col. 1 week means u are specifying time duration which requires dates or time field.

Otherwise you can keep a Status Column whose values are active or inactive. Each time row is displayed to user, you can update the status to inactive

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need a date column. You could add one today, allowing all previous entries in the table to be null for that field, and have it start populating from now. After a week, your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

auto-incrementing id can be helpful.save a record id(last inserted record id).After a week compare id's with that specific record id will result you the newer rows as all the rows with larger id's will be of last week